# Boto3 start_text_translation_job TooManyRequestsException

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, translate

Error in Python running Boto3 start_text_translation_job

```
botocore.errorfactory.TooManyRequestsException: An error occurred (TooManyRequestsException) when calling the StartTextTranslationJob operation: Request failed due to too many requests.
```

I wrote a Python script to kick off batch translation from EN to 48 languages. The first 10 submitted fine, but the 11th one got the above error.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I thought I had to slow down and put a sleep between the calls, but that was NOT the issue.

I tried to start a job using the AWS web console, and got a similar error:

```
Request failed due to too many requests.
```

This page on [AWS Translate Limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/what-is-limits.html) indicates that you can only have 10 translation jobs started at the same time.

Comment: If you contact support they might be able to increase that for you. You should never need to implement `sleep` in boto3 code because it has built-in retry logic to handle API throttling https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html

Comment: We have put in a request to raise some other Translate limits, but that was not included.  Can't wait for them now...